# Radio buttons in form do not transfer to another web page

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I can not see why my code does not take me to the specified webpage when dealing with my radio buttons:

```
<form name="login" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  method="post">
.
.
<input type="radio" name="ans1" id="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans2" id="no">No<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick= "where_to_go();">
</form>
```

Script for `where_to_go()`:

```
function where_to_go(){
    if (document.login.getElementById('yes').checked) {
        // Yes is chosen
        document.location.href = "Admin_index.html";

    }   else if (document.login.getElementById('no').checked) {
        // No is chosen
        document.location.href ="Log-In_Greet.php";
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me where did I go wrong at?

Comment: First, you want to use the same `name` attribute for radio buttons so the user wouldn't be able to select multiple radio buttons.


And second, for the script try using `document.getElementById('yes').checked`, when you have an `id` for something theres no need for more selectors since there should be only one element with that `id`.

Comment: can you set this up as a snippet and also show us your validateForm() function

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

---

The first would be revealed if you had looked at your browser's Developer Tool's Console (and had log preservation enabled so it wouldn't be wiped when you navigated to a new page).

`getElementById` is a property of the `document` object and only the `document` object. It is not a property of `document.logic` so trying to call `document.login.getElementById` will throw an exception.

---

Second: You are running your JS when you submit the form.

The JS runs, tells the browser to navigate to one of two pages (or would if the above problem wasn't there), then the form submission continues and tells the browser to navigate to the form's `action` URL (which you haven't specified so is "the current URL"). This overrides the URL set in the JS.

The quick and dirty solution is to `return false` from the `onclick` function so that the normal behaviour of the submit button is cancelled.

The very slightly less dirty approach would be to use `type="button"` so you wouldn't be triggering a form submission in the first place.

The robust approach would be to write server side code which tests, on a POST request, which submit button was used and issues an HTTP redirect. This will work when the JS [inevitably fails](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

The cleanest, simplest, most reliable approach is to **replace the radio buttons with simple links**.